# How to check if char is a certain character

Tags: java, arrays

I want to ask someone to type in a letter, and when they do, check if that letter is a certain letter that I am asking them. If it is, my output will display a list of an array. My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String[] rodent;
    String[] dog;
    String[] cat;

    rodent = new String[] {"Rat", "Guinea Pig", "Mouse"};
    dog = new String[] {"Rottweiler", "Basset Hound", "Weiner Dog"};
    cat = new String[] {"Lion", "Tiger", "Mountain Lion"};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please Enter [R] for Rodent, [D] for Dogs, and"
            + " [C] for Cats: ");
    char character = input.next().charAt(0);

    if(character == 'R'); {
        System.out.print(rodent[0]+", "+rodent[1]+", "+rodent[2]);
        } // closes 'R' statement
    if(character == 'D') {
        System.out.print(dog[0]+", "+dog[1]+", "+dog[2]);
    } //closes 'D' statement
    if(character == 'C') {
        System.out.print(cat[0]+", "+cat[1]+", "+cat[2]);
    } //closes 'C' statement
}
```

If they enter R, it outputs correctly.

If they enter D, it outputs rodents, and dogs.

If they enter C, it outputs just rodents.

What would be the fix to this?

Comment: `if(character == 'R'); {` <-- you have a stray semicolon here.  Maybe not a complete fix, but it should fix some of the problems.

Comment: `rodents` will always be printed because it's not in the `if`'s then clause, you have a semicolon there.

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed because of the unwanted semicolon BUT always try to use switch-case structure for these kinds of checks for the best practice.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] rodent;
    String[] dog;
    String[] cat;

    rodent = new String[] {"Rat", "Guinea Pig", "Mouse"};
    dog = new String[] {"Rottweiler", "Basset Hound", "Weiner Dog"};
    cat = new String[] {"Lion", "Tiger", "Mountain Lion"};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please Enter [R] for Rodent, [D] for Dogs, and"
            + " [C] for Cats: ");
    char character = input.next().charAt(0);


    switch (character){
        case 'R': System.out.print(rodent[0]+", "+rodent[1]+", "+rodent[2]);break;
        case 'D': System.out.print(dog[0]+", "+dog[1]+", "+dog[2]);break;
        case 'C': System.out.print(cat[0]+", "+cat[1]+", "+cat[2]);break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty new to Java so this is something I will study upon and practice. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Vexumy you're doing good, keep up with the good work, and good luck !

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

`if(character == 'R'); {`

Remove the `;` which terminates the `if` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm relatively new to coding, and new to Java so something so simple is hard for me to catch. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrong semicolon in your code:

```
if(character == 'R'); {
```

Delete it and your code will work!

The Semicolon says that your if statement is finished - so that the following part

```
{
    System.out.print(rodent[0]+", "+rodent[1]+", "+rodent[2]);
} // closes 'R' statement
```

is not part of your first `if`.
So the above statement will always be printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm relatively new to coding, and new to Java so something so simple is hard for me to catch. Thanks! :)